# Como formatar número em 2 casas decimais

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
  function calcular() {
   var p = parseFloat(document.getElementById('peso').value);
   var e = parseFloat(document.getElementById('estatura').value);
   document.getElementById('imc').value = p / ((e * e) / 10000);                                
  }
</script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="imc" name="imc" onblur="calcular()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a função [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) no seu cálculo.

```
function calcular() {
    var p = parseFloat(document.getElementById('peso').value);
    var e = parseFloat(document.getElementById('estatura').value);
    document.getElementById('imc').value = (p / ((e * e) / 10000)).toFixed(2) //duas casas decimais;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Laércio, mas não está funcionando, o número continua aparecendo com varias casas decimais depois do ponto.

Comment: funcionou ao retirar o ponto e virgula ";" . Alguma dica para aprender javascript na internet?